# Convert AngularJS website to Flask

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I created an Angular website with ui-router:

```
angular app structure
|--index.html
|--js
   |--app.js
   |--angular.js 
   |-- ...
|--stylesheets
   |--main.css
   |-- ...
|--template 
   |--navbar.html
   |--about.html
   |-- ...
```

Each js and css is linked like this:

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

I want to serve this with Flask. I threw everything in the "templates" folder and wrote a simple Flask app:

`server.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def view():
    return make_response(open('templates/index.html').read())

app.debug = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

```
flask app
|--server.py
|--templates
   |--index.html
   |--js
      |--app.js
      |--angular.js 
      |-- ...
   |--stylesheets
      |--main.css
      |-- ...
   |--template 
      |--navbar.html
      |--about.html
      |-- ...
```

None of my file are loading when I go to the root url.  How do I serve the Angular files from the Flask app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, move your all of the `.js` file and the `.css` file into a **static** directory and do something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
```

Put this in your templates before `</head>`, it will loads `static/main.css`.

And this will loads the `static/app.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='app.js') }}"></script>
```

About why, [here is the document](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#static-files).

Comment: `stylesheets` won't work here. `url_for` takes the name of an endpoint, not a folder.

Comment: @dirn Oops, let me fix it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to render your template. The best way to do that is

```
@app.route('/')
def view():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: Well, I also forgot this. But maybe we need *merge* our answers? :)